# There exist $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{k}$ such two inequality $|x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{k}|\ge 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers, contest-math

**Edit**: This problem 1 is a 2014 Sydney mathematics competition problem (8th grade). It seems difficult to solve.

> Show that:
>
> There exist  complex numbers $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{k}(k\ge 2)$ such that:
>   $$\begin{cases}
> |x^2_{1}+x^2_{2}+\cdots+x^2_{m}|\le\frac{1}{2} \text{ for all } m \le k\\
> |x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{k}|\ge 1.
> \end{cases}$$

Comment: Just to be clear: the second inequality is $k$, not $m$? So the first is true for all $m \le k$, and the second only for $k$?

Comment: @dtldarek:  Don't know how to do that. I could delete the comments.

Comment: @AndréNicolas You could make your comment an answer (i.e. retype it) or see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/13738/26306).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x_i=\frac{1}{k}$ for $i=1$ to $k$. Then both inequalities hold.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have add the 12-grade problem,I think the problem 2 is not easy to find it,But I think maybe you also can help it Thank you

Comment: sorry,it's 11-grad-problem

Comment: @DanRobertson Why not? $\sum_{i=1}^m x_i^2 = \frac{m}{k^2} \leq \frac{1}{k} \leq \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @Thailandasw: Yes, it looks more difficult. Currently it may be incomplete, it is not clear what $C=A\setminus B$ has to do with it. I will look in tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

For $k=1,$ there is no solution as $|x_1|\ge 1 \Rightarrow |x_1^2|\ge1.$

For $k\ge 2,$ set $x_j=(-i)^j\frac{-i}{\sqrt2}$ for all $j.$ Now let $S_m=|x^2_1+\cdots+x^2_m|.$ For an even $m,$ it should be clear that $S_m=0.$ For an odd $m,$ we have $S_m=|\frac12|=\frac12.$

Now let $T_k=|x_1+\cdots+x_k|.$ If $k>1$ then considering that $|x_1+x_2|=1$ we get $T_{2k}=|k(x_1+x_2)|=k$ and $T_{2k+1}=|k(x_1+x_2)+\frac1{\sqrt 2}|\ge k.$ The result follows.

Comment: also Nice example.+1