# There exist $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{k}$ such two inequality $|x^b_{1}+x^b_{2}+\cdots+x^b_{k}|\ge 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, contest-math, examples-counterexamples

This problem is a 2014 Sydney mathematics competition problem (11 grade). It seems difficult to solve. (I previously posted the [n=2 case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359134/there-exist-x-1-x-2-cdots-x-k-such-two-inequality-x-1x-2-cdots) for which André Nicolas and Dan Robertson proposed solutions)

> Let $A\subseteq X=\{1,2,3,\cdots,n\}$, $B=X\setminus A$. Show that: There exist  complex numbers $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{k}(k\ge 2)$ such that:
>   $$\begin{cases}
> \forall  a\in A,|x^a_{1}+x^a_{2}+\cdots+x^a_{m}|\le\frac{1}{a} \text{ for all } m \le k\\
> \forall  b\in B,|x^b_{1}+x^b_{2}+\cdots+x^b_{k}|\ge 1.
> \end{cases}$$